# How to tokenize on regex pattern and sort the resulting list?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
select a,b,c FROM Xtable
select a,b,c FROM Vtable
select a,b,c FROM Atable
select a,b,c FROM Atable
select d,e,f FROM Atable
```

I want to get a sortedMap:

```
{
"Atable":["select a,b,c FROM Atable", "select d,e,f FROM Atable"],
"Vtable":["select a,b,c FROM Vtable"],
"Xtable":["select a,b,c FROM Xtable"]
}
```

The keys of `sortedMap` will be tableName and values being the textline in list.

I started off with this, but stuck in tokenizing the line for regex matching:

```
import re

f = open('mytext.txt', 'r')
x = f.readlines()
print x
f.close()
for i in x:
    p = re.search(".* FROM ", i)
 //now how to tokenize and get the value that follows FROM
```

Comment: Here you go `(.*FROM[ \t]+(\S+))`

Comment: @sln how do I get the token right after FROM? i.e Atable, Btable etc

Comment: Python does not have sortedMap, it has OrderedDict.

Comment: @eagertoLearn - Group 1 = `select a,b,c FROM Atable` , Group 2 = `Atable` , then compose how ever you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `defaultdict` and regular expressions. Let `lines` be a list of your lines:

```
from collections import defaultdict
pattern = "(select .+ from (\S+).*)"
results = defaultdict(list)

for line in lines:
     query, table = re.findall(pattern, line.strip(), flags=re.I)[0]
     results[table].append(query)
```

Actually, the right way to read the file would be:

```
with open('mytext.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
         query, table = re.findall(pattern, line.strip(), flags=re.I)[0]
         results[table].append(query)
```

The result is, naturally, a `defaultdict`. If you want to convert it into an ordered dictionary, call the dictionary constructor:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(results.items()))
#OrderedDict([('Atable', ['select a,b,c FROM Atable', ...
```

You can make the `pattern` more robust to keep track of commas, valid identifiers, etc.

Comment: it doesnt look like sorted dict?

Comment: works great. couple of things I noticed with my test data. there is one kind of query like "select a,b,c from TableX where id=10" and "select a,b, (select d,e from Table Y) from TableX". In both the cases, I expect "TableX" to be key and value to the query.

Comment: so basically get the next token from last "FROM" in select statement. With the current one, I get key as "TableX where id=10" which is not correct

Comment: you mentioned it is hard problem to solve and you did in a minute :). This works great. I am running on a big file now. I will accept this once it is finishes. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

We most likely might not want to do this task with regular expressions, yet if we do, we
can start with a simple expression, maybe similar to:

```
\"(.+?([a-z]+))\"
```

We would replace it with `"\2":["\1"],`, then we would add a `{}`.

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\"(.+?([a-z]+))\""

test_str = ("\"select a,b,c FROM Xtable\"\n"
    "\"select a,b,c FROM Vtable\"\n"
    "\"select a,b,c FROM Atable\"\n"
    "\"select a,b,c FROM Atable\"\n"
    "\"select d,e,f FROM Atable\"")

subst = "\"\\2\":[\"\\1\"],"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pN0xwp/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: if not regex, how else you would like to do then?

Comment: and it fails if I remove double quotes, for example `select a,b,c FROM Xtable`

Comment: The result would be a string, not a dict.